# Excel 2013, combine CountIF + VLookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following issue, and I need advice on which formulas to use or if I'm better off trying some VBA codes? (I have no idea!):
I'm working at an Excel 2013 sheet which has the following data (Simplyfying to make you understand better)

> NamesColumn | DatesColumn | OtherColumns

- All entries are sorted by date, from oldest to most recent
- Both columns will contain duplicate data (a combination of same name and/or date, they differ from each other by what is put in the OtherColumns)
- Several times each week, I add entries to the sheet manually

Now, I need the following to happen when I add an entry: I want to be alerted (somehow, doesn't matter how - conditional formatting, sound or even just something "written" in an adjacent cell) if that same name (NamesColumn) has appeared 3 times or more in the previous 720 days (DatesColumn).

I'm also adding a little example with 5 entries and how the sheet has to behave every time I add one entry (from 1 to 5)

1. Bob | 01.01.2010 -> nothing happens only 1 bob in the 720 days prior to 01.01.2010
2. Bob | 01.01.2012 -> nothing happens only 1 bob in the 720 days prior to 01.01.2012
3. Bob | 01.02.2012 -> nothing happens only 2 bob in the 720 days prior to 01.02.2012
4. Bob | 01.03.2012 -> ALERT! Bob appears 3 or more times in the 720 days prior to 01.03.2012
5. Bob | 01.01.2016 -> nothing happens only 1 bob in the 720 days prior to 01.01.2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first row has labels and the data starts in row 2:

Select cell A2 down to the last cell of data in column A, then create a new conditional format with a rule. Use this rule:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,"<="&$B2,$B:$B,">="&$B2-720,$A:$A,$A2)>=3
```

[image]

If you turn the data entry table into an Excel Table (using Insert Table), the conditional format will automatically be applied to rows that are added to the table.

Comment: +1 for the excellent answer. Can you please elaborate on how the formula works (when you have time). I'm interested to know how it works

Comment: @Prasanna, well, it counts how many cells meet the three conditions. If the count is greater or equal to 3, then the format is applied. What part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula to show the number of occurences in past 720 days:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A8,A8,($B$2:$B8),">="&B8-$C$1)
```

You can then apply conditional formatting to highlight the frequent occurrences.

[image: Excel spreadsheet]